# Is there a key shortcut in SumatraPDF for inverse search?

Tags: sumatrapdf, vim-latex

I recently use vim-LaTeX and SumatraPDF for editing LaTeX document.

When I type `\lv` to perform forward search, I have to double click my mouse to perform inverse search.

Is there any key shortcuts to return back for inverse search (return back to source file)?

Comment: I don't think there is any.The concept is meaningleass IMO as you have to pin point at some word to inverse search which can't be done with short cut key but mouse click.

Comment: @HarishKumar: Sometimes I just want to see the whole effect of my work, and then return back to my source quickly.